# When executing a pyinstaller .exe file, pygame raises an error

Tags: python, tkinter, pygame, exe, pyinstaller

I'm making a little game using mainly Tkinter, but for sounds I used pygame.

I've been trying to make an .exe file but it gives me an error when I execute.

```
pygame.init()

self.sound_player_shot = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/shot.wav')
self.sound_gameover = pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/gameover.wav')

pygame.mixer.music.load('sounds/soundtrack.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)
```

That's the only codes from pygame that I use, and after creating the .exe file and copying all the data folders to the `dist` folder, when executing that error occurs:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
  File "space_shooter.py", line 1292, in start_game
  File "space_shooter.py", line 115, in __init__
pygame.error
```

The `sounds` folder is in the same folder of `space_shooter.py`, and all my other smaller projects worked just by copying all the data folders into `dist`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether the path you specify to load the sound files from are truly the paths you intend to use? An option might be to `print(path)` and start the exe from CMD to check it manually.

Without a more specific error message and knowing in which line the error actually originates, it is hard to give a more specific answer.

Furthermore I suggest you use the `os` module to get and set paths:

```
import os
dirname = os.path.dirname(__file__)
filename = os.path.join(dirname, 'relative/path/to/file/you/want.mp3')
```

PS: you might want to think about refactoring your "space_shooter.py" file, 1292 lines in one file sounds like a bit long in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Including data with pyinstaller-compiled programs can be done at compile-time. There you can link a path to an actual file on your computer (relative or absolute) with an alias path you use in the program itself.

[The documentation](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#adding-data-files) describes this process pretty well.